working out dice probabilities with permutations/combinations
I'm working on a maths problem about finding the probability of getting '8' after throwing two fair 6-sided dice. I know the answer is 5/36 from looking at all possibilities of adding numbers 1-6.So, I have 2+6, 3+5, 4+4, 5+3 and 6+2.
The problem is I'm not sure how to work this out using permutations and combinations as this is the point of the exercise.
My first thought was to do $\frac {({6C1 * 6C1})*5} {12C2}$ . My thinking was the order doesn't matter for which the numbers are read but that we need to multiply by 5 as there are 5 possible true event. I wasn't confident that the denominator was accurate but I know the answer was wrong as it is 5/22
I Have had other ideas but because I know the answer I'm generally using ad hoc intuition. Is there a proper way to solve this?

Why do you think you need to use permutations and combinations?  Particularly for such a problem?

It was part of a exercise with other perms and combs questions so I assume that how it is meant to be solved

This problem does not lend itself to solving by permutations or combinations.

Can i ask why that is the case?

Your ordered appoach to counting looks good to me.    If you take the sums with on dice you get 1 1 1 1 1 1 with sum to 1 to 6.  Convolve with 1 1 1 1 1 1  and get one permutation with sum 2.   The counts for sums of  is 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1.    Starts with sum 2 and you get 5 answers sum to eight.  Divide by 6^2.   (Multinomial equivalent to Pascal's triangle.)  You were effectively doing this with how you found sums to 8.

For the denominator, we can use the Multiplication Principle to obtain $6 \cdot 6 = 36$ possible outcomes.  For the numerator, simply listing the favorable cases is the easiest way to find the number of favorable cases.  If you insist on a more formal solution, you could find the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 = 8$ in the positive integers subject to the restriction that $x_1, x_2 \leq 6$.  However, that is more work than simply listing the favorable cases.

Expanding on the comment of @N.F.Taussig, see this answer
for a blueprint of how to combine Inclusion-Exclusion with Stars-And-Bars to attack this generic type of problem.  The original constraints are $$x_1 + x_2 = 8, ~~~x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}, ~~1 \leq x_1,x_2 \leq 6.$$  The final computation is $~\dfrac{N}{D} ~: ~D = 6^2,~$ and $$N = \left{ ~\binom{7}{1} - \left[ ~2 \times \binom{0}{0} ~\right] ~\right}.$$

The result $\frac{5}{36}$ is correct. In case of doubt I would always resort back to looking at the individual draws to decompose the problem into manageable sub problems. Decomposition is a good strategy for many difficult problems:
Let's look at the denominator (all possible throws) first:
Throwing 2 dice is like drawing twice from an urn containing the numbers 1-6, putting the number back after each draw. Hence, there are $n^k_a=6^2=36$ possible outcomes/permutations that occur with equal probability. Looking at each individual draw: $n_{a1}^k*n_{a2}^k=6^1*6^1=36$
Now, the numerator (all throws that sum to 8):
Observe that you cannot get the sum 8, if the first draw is a 1 (that you have to see). Hence, for the first draw there are only 5 numbers in the urn (2-6), which makes $n_{b1}^k=5^1$ permutations. Then for the second draw there is only a single feasible option left to draw a number so both numbers sum to 8, which makes $n_{b2}^k=1^1$ total possibilities. To get the number of ways to draw two numbers that equal 8, you compute $n_{b1}^k*n_{b2}^k$.
This yields:
$\frac{n_{b1}^k*n_{b2}^k}{n_{a1}^k*n_{a2}^k}=\frac{5^1*1^1}{6^1*6^1}=\frac{5}{36}$
You can of course use the binomial operator to count options for each draw, which yields:
$\frac{5C1*1C1}{6C1*6C1}$
I can't rule out that there is some more elegant way for this specific problem to calculate probability.

See my comment, following the posted question.  It is very arguable whether my (overall) approach is more elegant than yours.  However, it does represent an alternative approach.
